# getting both "a" text and regular text on scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following span:

```
<span class="name">

    bla bla <a href="address">foo</a> bar
</span>
```

I want scrapy to extract the entire sentence without the link, meaining:
`bla bla foo bar`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `descendant-or-self::*/text()` xpath expression:

```
//span[@class="name"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()
```

Demo (using [scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)):

```
$ cat index.html 
<span class="name">bla bla <a href="address">foo</a> bar</span>
$ scrapy shell index.html
>>> results = sel.xpath('//span[@class="name"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()').extract()
>>> ''.join(results)
u'bla bla foo bar'
```